# Confidence Interval - small dataset (30 records)

Tags: confidence-interval, z-score, z-statistic

I'm trying to calculate a confidence interval for data analyst salary population. I have a very small dataset from a job posting site that contains only 30 records. The dataset doesn't follow normal distribution, which is to my knowledge a requirement for a z-table

I don't know how to approach the issue. Is it even possible to use Central Limit Thorem to make this dataset normally distributed? It seems that the dataset is too small for that.

What are your suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: [CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) doesn't turn a given sample with a non-normal distribution into one that does.

Comment: You can compute z sores of non-normal variables. They're just not guaranteed to have a standard normal distribution, making the usual table of z scores inapplicable without more information.

Comment: Why not compute the lower and upper $1-\alpha$ of the data for the CI?

Answer (score 2):

Salaries are notoriously non-normal. I might start by assuming salaries to be exponentially distributed.

Then for a sample of size $n \approx 30,$ I would want to compare the traditional t CI $(62.45, 157.96)$ with one from bootstrapping $(62.64, 148.57)$, and also from an exact exponential CI $(79.38, 163.34),$ pivoting $\frac{\bar X}{\mu}\sim\mathsf{Gamma}(n,n).$

```
set.seed(2022)
x = rexp(30, .01)  # Fictitious sample of 30
boxplot(x, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

```
a.obs = mean(x)
[1] 110.2023

set.seed(618)
d = replicate(2000, mean(sample(x,30,rep=T))-a.obs)
UL = quantile(d, c(.975,.025))
CI.boot = a.obs - UL;  CI.boot
   97.5%     2.5% 
 62.6378 148.5748 

CI.t = t.test(x)$conf.int; CI.t
[1]  62.44823 157.95632
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95

a.obs/qgamma(c(.975,.025), 30,30)
[1]  79.3796 163.3362
```